# 404s on password protected content

Tags: seo, wordpress, 404, web-crawlers

I'm new to WordPress and SEO, generally, but we've been running into problems with our site that don't seem to make sense to me.

The problem is that our editor likes to schedule posts and/or mark them private until she is ready to make them public, but somehow Google is crawling these posts and getting 404s (because they are password protected). How does Google know they exist in the first place? I checked the sitemap.xml file and don't see a record of the post. One of the offending posts was marked public, but is scheduled for a future date. Could that have something to do with it?

I've tried to Google the answer, and I came up with a good amount of reassurance that this won't hurt the site, but I'm still wondering how it's happening in the first place. It's hard because I don't know exactly what the editor's workflow is. Is it possible she's posting publicly first and then revising it to be private only after it's too late?

Does anyone know how Google finds WordPress URLs it shouldn't have access to?

Comment: What is your URL structure?

Comment: `http://www.site.com/blog/2011/12/this-is-a-post-dont-you-like-it/`

Comment: Double check with your editor to get the exact workflow she's using.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is some link to the article somewhere on your site. Otherwise it shouldn't happen IMO.

Comment: If something is password protected, shouldn't it return a 403 - Access Denied, rather than a 404 - Not found?

Comment: @w3d perhaps, but the way it is currently set up is to return a 404 instead.

Comment: @PeeHaa I think it ends up being linked as recent or related on other posts or something liek that, but I haven't been able to catch it in action

Comment: @ChrisF I have an email out to the editor to see what her process is. She's very not technical. What should I be asking her specifically (so she doesn't get confused/overwhelmed)?

Comment: Wait to see what she replies to your first e-mail then try to follow the process yourself. If you get stuck or it's not clear ask her the specific questions to get over that bit.

Comment: When she's got a scheduled/private post get her to tell you the URL and then see if you can see it when you're not logged in. You could also check to see if it appears on other posts as related.

Comment: Maybe Wordpress pings Google to let it know that a new post was created?

Comment: @paulmorriss I still haven't heard back from her, but I have admin rights to the blog, so I can see the private posts. I checked for access to private URLs and wasn't able to access them. My thinking is that she is publishing them first and then setting them to private or unpublished after the fact, but I won't be sure until she tells me. The revision history doesn't seem to record whether it was published, privatized, unpublished, etc.

Comment: @ZippyV that's an interesting idea. To my knowledge that's not how Google works, but my knowledge is not extensive as you might have guessed. I'll look into it.

Comment: @tjb1982 By default Wordpress pings some website that submits it to a lot of other websites. It's in your Settings -> Writing -> (at the bottom) Update Services. Try removing that url and see if it still happens.

Comment: @ZippyV aha. I see it. However, it shouldn't ping this URL if the post is marked private or future-dated. Do you know where/what file this feature is implemented in the WordPress codebase?

Answer (score 1):

Actually in WordPress after creating a Post in the top right you can click the edit link next to `Publish immediately Edit` and set the future date the Post should be published. This is better than setting them to private and then public.

Google is finding them because when a Post is created WordPress pings Google and other sites letting them know of the new post. You might also have a sitemap plugin generating the URL in the sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

Private - WordPress will create a post that is accessible to users/viewers, but the content of that post will be hidden until its unlocked. I would suggest saving it as a Draft.